# Fastlane - upload_to_testflight - Unable to process validateMetadata request at this time due to a general error (1019)

Tags: ios, fastlane

Trying to upload to Testflight for beta release by Fastlane and getting this error message

```
Unable to process validateMetadata request at this time due to a general error (1019)
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: Unable to process validateMetadata request at this time due to a general error (1019)
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

I'm new to Fastlane and possibly missing something.

Fastfile

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

  desc "Build for distribution (via App Store and TestFlight)"
  lane :release do
    ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "*****************"
    increment_build_number(
        xcodeproj: "----------------"
    )
    upload_to_testflight(
      username: "----------------",
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
      apple_id: '----------------',
      reject_build_waiting_for_review: false
    )
  end

end
```

Comment: Let me know what debug info is required.